# How to fetch a value from XML using XPATH

Tags: java, xml, xpath

This is my xml and i wanted to fetch value of Id tag '4654'

```
<Entity>
       <acc>
            <id>4654</id>
            <name>abc</name>
       </acc>
       <acc>
            <id>5465</id>
            <name>xyz</name>
       </acc>
```

I am using this code to retrieve the Id value

```
       DocumentBuilderFactory factory =    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
       Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml))); 
       XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
       NodeList  node = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("/Entity/acc/id/text()", document, XPathConstants.NODE);
       System.out.println("node length:"+node.getLength());
       System.out.println("node value:"+ node.item(0).getNodeValue());
       return node.item(0).getNodeValue();
```

Output returns null

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: which output is null?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `XPathConstants.NODESET` instead of `XPathConstants.NODE`

or you can keep it as `XPathConstants.NODE` and change the evaluate to return `Node`

`Node  node = (Node) xPath.evaluate("/Entity/acc/id/text()", document, XPathConstants.NODE);`